# Append information in the th tags to td rows

Tags: html, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am an economist struggling with coding and data scraping.
I am scarping data from the main and unique table on this webpage (https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/europe/euroleague-2013-2014/results/). I can retrieve all the information of the td HTML tags with python selenium by referring to the class element. The same goes for the th tag where it is stored the information of the date and stage of the competition. In my final dataset, I would like to have the information stored in the th tag in two rows (data and stage of the competition) next to the other rows in the table. Basically, for each match, I would like to have the date and the stage of the competition in rows and not as the head of each group of matches.
The only solution I came up with is to index all the rows (with both th and td tags) and build a while loop to append the information in the th tags to the td rows whose index is lower than the next index for the th tag. Hope I made myself clear (if not I will try to give a more graphical explanation). However, I am not able to code such a logic construct due to my poor coding abilities. I do not know if I need two loops to iterate through different tags (td and th) and in case how to do that. If you have any easier solution, it is more than welcome!
Thanks in advance for the precious help!

code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd

# Season to filter
seasons_filt = ['2013-2014', '2014-2015', '2015-2016','2016-2017', '2017-2018', '2018-2019']

# Define empty data
data_keys = ["Season", "Match_Time", "Home_Team", "Away_Team", "Home_Odd", "Away_Odd", "Home_Score",
             "Away_Score", "OT", "N_Bookmakers"]
data = dict()
for key in data_keys:
    data[key] = list()
del data_keys
    
# Define 'driver' variable and launch browser
#path = "C:/Users/ALESSANDRO/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"
#path office pc
path = "C:/Users/aldi/Downloads/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

# Loop through pages based on page_num and season
for season_filt in seasons_filt:
    page_num = 0
    while True:
        page_num += 1
                       
        # Get url and navigate it
        page_str = (1 - len(str(page_num)))* '0' + str(page_num)
        url ="https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/europe/euroleague-" + str(season_filt) + "/results/#/page/" + page_str + "/"
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(3)
        
        # Check if page has no data
        if driver.find_elements_by_id("emptyMsg"):
            print("Season {} ended at page {}".format(season_filt, page_num))
            break
        
        try:      
            # Teams
            for el in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('name.table-participant'):
                el = el.text.strip().split(" - ")
                data["Home_Team"].append(el[0])
                data["Away_Team"].append(el[1])
                data["Season"].append(season_filt)
            
            # Scores
            for el in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('center.bold.table-odds.table-score'):
                el = el.text.split(":")
                if el[1][-3:] == " OT":
                    data["OT"].append(True)
                    el[1] = el[1][:-3]
                else:
                    data["OT"].append(False)
                data["Home_Score"].append(el[0])
                data["Away_Score"].append(el[1])
            
            # Match times
            for el in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("table-time"):
                data["Match_Time"].append(el.text)
            
            # Odds
            i = 0
            for el in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("odds-nowrp"):
                i += 1
                if i%2 == 0:
                    data["Away_Odd"].append(el.text)
                else:
                    data["Home_Odd"].append(el.text)
                    
            # N_Bookmakers
            for el in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("center.info-value"):
                data["N_Bookmakers"].append(el.text)
            
            # TODO think of inserting the dates list in the dataframe even if it has a different size (19 rows and not 50)

        except:
            pass

driver.quit()

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data.to_csv("data_odds.csv", index = False)
```

I would like to add this information to my dataset as two additional rows:

```
for el in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("first2.tl")[1:]:
    el = el.text.strip().split(" - ")
    data["date"].append(el[0])
    data["stage"].append(el[1])
```

Comment: could you provide the full code you wrote?

Comment: I added the code to the post 

Answer (score 1):

Few things I would change here.

1. Don't overwrite variables. You store elements in your `el` variable, then you over write the element with your strings. It may work for you here, but you may get yourself into trouble with that practice later on, especially since you are iterating through those elements. It makes it hard to debug too.
2. I know Selenium has ways to parse the html. But I personally feel BeautifulSoup is a tad easier to parse with and is a little more intuitive if you are simply just trying to pull out data from the html. So I went with BeautifulSoup's `.find_previous()` to get the tags that precede the games, essentially then able to get your date and stage content.
3. Lastly, I like to construct a list of dictionaries to make up the data frame. Each item in the list is a dictionary key:value where the key is the column name and value is the data. You sort of do the opposite in creating a dictionary of lists. Now there is nothing wrong with that, but if the lists don't have the same length, you're get an error when trying to create the dataframe. Where as with my way, if for what ever reason there is a value missing, it will still create the dataframe, but will just have a null or nan for the missing data.

There may be more work you need to do with the code to go through the pages, but this gets you the data in the form you need.

**Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

# Season to filter
seasons_filt = ['2013-2014', '2014-2015', '2015-2016','2016-2017', '2017-2018', '2018-2019']

    
# Define 'driver' variable and launch browser
path = "C:/Users/ALESSANDRO/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

rows = []
# Loop through pages based on page_num and season
for season_filt in seasons_filt:
    page_num = 0
    while True:
        page_num += 1
                       
        # Get url and navigate it
        page_str = (1 - len(str(page_num)))* '0' + str(page_num)
        url ="https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/europe/euroleague-" + str(season_filt) + "/results/#/page/" + page_str + "/"
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(3)
        
        # Check if page has no data
        if driver.find_elements_by_id("emptyMsg"):
            print("Season {} ended at page {}".format(season_filt, page_num))
            break
        
        try:      
            soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
            table = soup.find('table', {'id':'tournamentTable'})
            
            trs = table.find_all('tr', {'class':re.compile('.*deactivate.*')})
            for each in trs:
                teams = each.find('td', {'class':'name table-participant'}).text.split(' - ')
                scores = each.find('td', {'class':re.compile('.*table-score.*')}).text.split(':')
                ot = False
                for score in scores:
                    if 'OT' in score:
                        ot == True
                scores = [x.replace('\xa0OT','') for x in scores]
                matchTime = each.find('td', {'class':re.compile('.*table-time.*')}).text
                
                # Odds
                i = 0
                for each_odd in each.find_all('td',{'class':"odds-nowrp"}):
                    i += 1
                    if i%2 == 0:
                        away_odd = each_odd.text
                    else:
                        home_odd = each_odd.text
                        
                n_bookmakers = soup.find('td',{'class':'center info-value'}).text
                
                date_stage = each.find_previous('th', {'class':'first2 tl'}).text.split(' - ')
                date = date_stage[0]
                stage = date_stage[1]
                
                
                row = {'Season':season_filt,
                 'Home_Team':teams[0],
                 'Away_Team':teams[1],
                 'Home_Score':scores[0],
                 'Away_Score':scores[1],
                 'OT':ot,
                 'Match_Time':matchTime,
                 'Home_Odd':home_odd,
                 'Away_Odd':away_odd,
                 'N_Bookmakers':n_bookmakers,
                 'Date':date,
                 'Stage':stage}
                
                rows.append(row)
                
                

        except:
            pass

driver.quit()

data = pd.DataFrame(rows)
data.to_csv("data_odds.csv", index = False)
```

**Output:**

```
print(data.head(15).to_string())
       Season         Home_Team          Away_Team Home_Score Away_Score     OT Match_Time Home_Odd Away_Odd N_Bookmakers         Date       Stage
0   2013-2014       Real Madrid   Maccabi Tel Aviv         86         98  False      18:00     -667     +493            7  18 May 2014  Final Four
1   2013-2014         Barcelona        CSKA Moscow         93         78  False      15:00     -135     +112            7  18 May 2014  Final Four
2   2013-2014         Barcelona        Real Madrid         62        100  False      19:00     +134     -161            7  16 May 2014  Final Four
3   2013-2014       CSKA Moscow   Maccabi Tel Aviv         67         68  False      16:00     -278     +224            7  16 May 2014  Final Four
4   2013-2014       Real Madrid        Olympiacos          83         69  False      18:45     -500     +374            7  25 Apr 2014   Play Offs
5   2013-2014       CSKA Moscow     Panathinaikos          74         44  False      16:00     -370     +295            7  25 Apr 2014   Play Offs
6   2013-2014        Olympiacos       Real Madrid          71         62  False      18:45     +127     -152            7  23 Apr 2014   Play Offs
7   2013-2014  Maccabi Tel Aviv    Olimpia Milano          86         66  False      17:45     -217     +179            7  23 Apr 2014   Play Offs
8   2013-2014     Panathinaikos       CSKA Moscow          73         72  False      16:30     -106     -112            7  23 Apr 2014   Play Offs
9   2013-2014     Panathinaikos       CSKA Moscow          65         59  False      18:45     -125     +104            7  21 Apr 2014   Play Offs
10  2013-2014  Maccabi Tel Aviv    Olimpia Milano          75         63  False      18:15     -189     +156            7  21 Apr 2014   Play Offs
11  2013-2014        Olympiacos       Real Madrid          78         76  False      17:00     +104     -125            7  21 Apr 2014   Play Offs
12  2013-2014       Galatasaray         Barcelona          75         78  False      17:00     +264     -333            7  20 Apr 2014   Play Offs
13  2013-2014    Olimpia Milano  Maccabi Tel Aviv          91         77  False      18:45     -286     +227            7  18 Apr 2014   Play Offs
14  2013-2014       CSKA Moscow     Panathinaikos          77         51  False      16:15     -303     +247            7  18 Apr 2014   Play Offs
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You gave me a lot of helpful insights! I really appreciated that! 